# OKTA filters format

Tags: android, rest

I'm trying to execute the below query to list out users who are active & have changed the password  after a specific date/time.

URL:

```
{{url}}/api/v1/users?filter=status eq "ACTIVE" and passwordchanged gt "2014-10-08T10:10:45.000Z"
```

Output: Getting Bad Request . What is not ok with this ?

```
{
    "errorCode": "E0000031",
    "errorSummary": "Bad request. Invalid filter parameter.",
    "errorLink": "E0000031",
    "errorId": "oaeItfhZkMfQR-jmUvDt3bdbw",
    "errorCauses": []
}
```

I have gathered the date from one of the existing users in the same instance using a Get User query:

```
{{url}}/api/v1/users/00u2o0nvrmNMPNZILEQM
```

Answer (score 1):

The date is in the correct format, but passwordChanged isn't currently supported as a filter parameter for users.

The supported filters are listed here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/rest/users.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

Currently - we only support "lastUpdated" as a time-based filter.  Everything else looks ok.